# Excel Enter Value only IF Row contains specific text

Tags: excel-2010

I have this formula that I use to calculate lead-time for jobs which works great for what I have needed. Now my job data is going to change in each row and the data I need will not always be in the same column as it once was. What I need to do is add to my existing formula to only fill in the leadtime IF any cells in the row contain the text "COMPLETED", otherwise leave the cell blank.  Can anyone help with this?

```
=(IF(ISBLANK(P1),"",(IF(P1-G1<7,IF(WEEKDAY(P1)>WEEKDAY(P1),P1-G1-2,P1-G1),(P1-G1-(ROUNDDOWN((P1-G1)/7,0)*2))))))
```

Comment: In which cell is the formula ??

Comment: I haven't decided yet in what column this formula will be in. The data I am capturing is just a date difference (P1-G1) to give me the total leadtime of the job.  My finish time has always been in column N and each row is individual data. Now my finish data can be in any column up to column Z.  I create a moving average chart from the data so I need the column cells to stay blank like my formula does, but now I have to look for the "Completed" text in order to get a leadtime total.

Answer (score 1):

Test the value of a Match formula in another If statement to see if it's greater than 1, here's an example using your existing formula. This is for row 1 where the word 'COMPLETED' could be in columns B to Z:

=IF(IFERROR(MATCH("COMPLETED",B1:Z1,0),0)>0,"Completed",IF(ISBLANK(P1),"",(IF(P1-G1<7,IF(WEEKDAY(P1)>WEEKDAY(P1),P1-G1-2,P1-G1),(P1-G1-(ROUNDDOWN((P1-G1)/7,0)*2))))))

Comment: I still can't figure out how to add this to my formula above.

Comment: What I have determined so far is... I don't need to check if anything is greater than 1. What I need to do based on my original formula is to keep cell T1 "blank" like it does now unless "completed" is found in any cell in that row, then produce the results of my formula above. I cannot figure this out.